# how can i keep node expanded in sharepoint designer when grouping

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I have 2 Data view WebParts, one is being grouped by columns so it has expanded and collapsed; the other WebPart is a simple list but i have linked them up by setting up a parameter.

So on the first Data view WebPart i have a link on one of the column e.g `menu.aspx?code=234`

When click the link I do send the param to the second list(Data view WebPart) to filter some data. The problem is when I click on the link it doesn't keep the expanded selected but collapses all again.

How can I get it selected so users can see what they just clicked on the first Data view WebPart.

Comment: Seems no answer or ideas :(